# AUCTeX region preview in Emacs

Tags: emacs, auctex, preview

I've installed AUCTeX and passed the circ.tex preview, however, when I'm trying to add more elements (enumerate, tabular) to preview with `\PreviewEnvironment{..}` in the preamble, AUCTeX ignores these lines and render only math, table, sections, and other default elements. I've tried to add custom environments in `preview-default-preamble`, but no success.

It's probably a part of the same problem, but if I try `C-c C-p C-e` (preview the environment with a pointer inside this environment), it says `no enclosing outer environment found` -- a pretty rare error, Google finds it only in preview.el sources.

`preview-image-type` is set to `dvipng` (png and gswin32c.exe do not work properly).

Emacs 23.3 and TeX Live 2011 are the counterpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked through the problem and have three points to stress:

1. `\PreviewEnvironment` should not work in a tex file's preamble.
2. One way to add custom environments is by adding full `\PreviewEnvironment{..}` entries **after** the last string of the default Preview Default Preamble string (expected to be `]{preview}[2004/11/05]`). It's equivalent for .emacs: `(setq preview-default-preamble (quote ("\\RequirePackage[" ("," . preview-default-option-list) "]{preview}[2004/11/05]" "\\PreviewEnvironment{center}" "\\PreviewEnvironment{enumerate}")))`, where `center` and `enumerate` are example custom environments. Alternatives are ([preview-latex.pdf](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex.pdf), p. 11):

   - including custom environments in local file variables
   - a configuration file in the project's directory
3. `M-x preview-environment` (`C-c C-p C-e`) works only for the customized environments (see 2) and environments from `preview-default-option-list`.

Answer (score 1):

Point 1: PreviewEnvironment certainly works in the preamble *if* preview.sty has been loaded.  The AUCTeX component of preview-latex uses \AtBeginDocument for loading it in order to give the document itself a chance to load it with its own individual options.

Point 3: preview-environment most certainly works for any environment, but it likely does something different from what you expect it to do: it runs the region enclosed by the current environment through preview-latex, and everything that would be previewed inside of that region when running the whole document through preview-latex will get freshly previewed.